# Geniatagger -- error with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I tried to use the geniatagger.py from this link :

https://github.com/informationsea/geniatagger-python

So, I did manage to install it properly. Then, I tried to test it by using the example provided from README:

```
import geniatagger
tagger = GeniaTagger('geniatagger')
print tagger.parse('This is a pen.')
```

and here is what I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testtagger.py", line 3, in <module>
tagger = GeniaTagger('geniatagger')
File "/home/malliheedi/geniatagger-python-0.1/geniatagger.py", line 21, in __init__
stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

Could you please help me with that?

Your cooperation in this matter is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

[The library expects that you always include a directory name in the path](https://github.com/informationsea/geniatagger-python/blob/6fb98366ae22c1b25b9c475281c57f742ea8330a/geniatagger.py#L7):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.dirname('abc')
''
>>> os.path.dirname('./abc')
'.'
>>> os.chdir('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

To workaround, change `GeniaTagger('geniatagger')` to `GeniaTagger('./geniatagger')` (assuming there is `geniatagger` executable in the current directory otherwise provide the full path).

If `abc` should mean the same as `./abc` in this context then it is a bug and you should [open an issue.](https://github.com/informationsea/geniatagger-python/issues/new)